# Java ,For loop command

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

What is the meaning of this?

> for(Ship s: p.ships)

Ship is the class,
s is the object of the class Ship, 
and p is the player.

These are commands from the game Battleship.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < p.ships.size(); i++){
       Ship s = p.ships.get(0);
    }`

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/for-each-loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Comment: It iterates through all Ships contained in p, See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work

Comment: Along with lack of encapsulation, and poor variable naming.

Comment: @YCF_L ...p.ships.get(i)...

Comment: Basically the system is traversing the list of all the ships of a player.

Comment: exactly @ErinPaciorkowski

Answer (score 6):

This code means that `p.ships` is a some of collection implements inteface `Iterable`.

```
for(Ship s: p.ships)
```

It is a foreach loop. Syntax sugar which was introduced in java 5.

This is equivalent of this statement above:

```
for (Iterator<Ship > i = p.ships.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Ship s= i.next();
}
```